# Network devices down suddenly

Tags: ethernet, networking, troubleshooting

This is a home network with many wired and wireless devices. Yesterday I plugged in a bad CAT5e cable (Orange/White and Orange - Tx- & Tx+) were crossed. It seems I lost all internet access for my Netgear stuff (a. router/switch/firewall/gateway and 3 Netgear n routers configured as APs, and one brand new Netgear N300 router). Internet access isn't possible regardless whether the routers are in native or AP modes. In addition my Arris cable modem could not get DNS service from my ISP. Have spent countless hours on the phone with "Tech" support but to no avail - so all the obvious troubleshooting stuff has already occurred. I replaced the Arris modem with a Cisco DPC3939 and while I have basic internet service from it directly, I cannot seem to get these other devices to get internet access. I've even hard-wired the DNS Server IP addresses (primary & backup).

Am at wit's end and wanted to gather a few opinions before I start replacing gear. So, could a crossed pair of Tx's have damaged all this equipment? It was plugged into a Belkin 10/100 switch, which appears to be working properly. Go figure...

Thanks in advance.

BZ

Comment: The answer is no, a crossed TX pair isn't going to do that.  Are you sure you didn't just plug the network back into itself somewhere?  And this isn't the forum for this question.

Comment: I know your question wasn't how to revive things, but I thought I would suggest this nonetheless. It may be a shot in the dark, but I have used it twice with success in cases like you have described. Power down and unplug (de-energize) all network devices and computers for an hour. Reconnect network routers and modems first and wait a few minutes before connecting devices to the network.